# How to query Document directives in beancount query language?

Tags: accounting, beancount

I am a big fan of double-entry accounting from text files and use beancount: https://github.com/beancount/beancount
Using the beancount query language, I can easily create reports (e.g. tax) from my text files.

In beancount, it is possible to add links to documents (e.g. PDFs of the receipts) in the transaction statements as in

```
2020-02-04 * "Google" "Server" #tax
  document: "2020-02-04 3688657551.pdf"
  Liabilities:ErsteBank:Credit  -30.40 EUR
  Expenses:Professional:Server   30.40 EUR
```

At the end of the year, I use the following query to get all tax relevant expenses:

```
SELECT 
    account,  date, number as value, currency, description
FROM
    year = 2020
WHERE
    account ~ "Expenses:"
    AND 'tax' IN tags
ORDER BY date, account, betrag
```

Is it possible to include the filename of the Document directive in the query, i.e. "2020-02-04 3688657551.pdf"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Robert,
Try with the `any_meta('document')` as briefly introduced in this [post](https://groups.google.com/g/beancount/c/_vhyz7TqAMA/m/aYn5XbhkCQAJ).

Ledger:

```
2020-01-01 open Liabilities:ErsteBank:Credit
2020-01-01 open Expenses:Professional:Server
option "operating_currency" "EUR"


2020-02-04 * "Google" "Server" #tax
  document: "2020-02-04 3688657551.pdf"
  Liabilities:ErsteBank:Credit  -30.40 EUR
  Expenses:Professional:Server   30.40 EUR
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    account, date, number as value, payee, any_meta('document') as document
FROM
    year = 2020
WHERE
    account ~ "Expenses:"
    AND 'tax' IN tags
ORDER BY date, account
```

Result:

| account | date | value | payee | document |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Expenses:Professional:Server | 2020-02-04 | 30.40 | Google | 2020-02-04 3688657551.pdf |